# When evaluating limits can I let the constant approach the variable? Even when using L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus

Consider a function of two variables 
$$
f(x,y) 
$$
say one want to consider a limit like
$$
\lim_{x \to y} f(x,y)
$$
and that it exists. Is it then the same to consider 
$$
\lim_{x \to y} f(y,x)
$$
given it exists? Specifically assume
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{g(x,y)}{h(x,y)}
$$
and that evaluating the limit evolves resolving an indertiminate form, would I then could use L'Hopital by taking the derivative with respect to the variable I please using the above?

I'm feeling it should obviously be fine writing it up like the above, but in concrete cases it feels kind of eerie to make the "constant approach the variable" so to speak and differentiate with respect to the constant.

Comment: What actually is $f(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Consider $f(x,y)=x^y$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x,0)=1$ whereas $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(0,x)=0$.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Are there checkable conditions that makes it work?

Comment: If the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous, then such problems disappear.